# Aws s3 object acl everyone read access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I have upload one image but its not publicly accessible. I have granted full AWS s3 permission for the user. My canonical user id 9ebb86750cf9111e69a4c95e1c3c53062209080c56399ddc7919be48897cf25f. Same as attached screenshot. Screenshot link:

While I am pressing make public button or give public permission in ACL by checking "everyone". It is showing that "Access denied". Recently I have seen that AWS has ACL for bucket and object. There is CORS configuration.

What could be the possible cause? My IAM has administrator access and s3full access.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJcFw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HURF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEnEt.png)

Comment: Unfortunately you haven't given us enough information to help you. Suggest you edit your post to include screenshots of all relevant screens - IAM permissions, object permissions, bucket permissions, all error messages.

Comment: Screenshot Included

Answer (score 0):

If "Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects (Recommended)" under public access settings of bucket is set to true, you will not be able to add any new ACL's granting public access. 
Hope this helps.[screenshot of the settings from bucket page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbyqp.png)